# DateFormatter Returning with Valid String

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

My date from a string is always nil and I can't figure out why.

```
func getBirthdate() -> Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        print(self.dob!)
        let birthdate = formatter.date(from: self.dob!)
        return birthdate
    }
```

self.dob:

```
05/01/1984
```

Comment: `dateStyle` and ` timeStyle` is overriding your format. Delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either set `.dateFormat` or `.dateStyle`/`.timeStyle`.
They are mutually exclusive, when you set `.dateStyle` you reset `.dateFormat` to one of preset date formats.

So, it should be:

```
func getBirthdate() -> Date? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter() // Also, you should move initialisation out and reuse `DateFormatter`
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    print(self.dob!)
    let birthdate = formatter.date(from: self.dob!)
    return birthdate
}
```